# Git not visible in RStudio (windows)

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I am very new to using rstudio/git and I have had an issue setting it up so I was hoping someone could help. The git buttons are not visible in RStudio on my windows pc.

I can open my repository from GitHub and the git executable seems to be in the correct location. However, the git buttons are not visible so I cannot commit and push any changes.

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Did you [follow the installation steps](https://jennybc.github.io/2014-05-12-ubc/ubc-r/session03_git.html), and if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to do it exactly as the instructions stated for installing. I also checked that the git executable is in the correct folder. I then opened a repository from GitHub which worked fine too. However, the git button is not visible on the screen and when I go to project options and to "Git/SVN" and change it from "none" to "git" it says "incorrect function".

Comment: Can you open the Git bash from the Git folder?

Comment: Yes but it says that its unlikely to be a valid git executable.

Comment: OK I'm trying to ascertain whether or not Git is even installed correctly.  Obviously, if it isn't, then the R plugin won't work.

Comment: I understand - yes that seems to work. And sorry, just to be clear, are you suggesting that git isn't installed properly (as I don't know how this was done as I have a university PC and IT does this given my restricted admin rights)? Sorry about all the questions.

Comment: `Open RStudio` | `Click Tools -> Global Options -> Git/SVN` | `If Git executable shows (none), click Browse and select the git executable installed on your system` ..._Did you follow these exact steps_ ?

Comment: Yes, I have the following: C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Comment: Random thought: Can you try loading your R console in admin mode?  Right click the R icon and choose run as administrator.  I speculate that perhaps R does not have the necessary rights to use Git.

Comment: I currently can't as I don't have admin rights as its a university computer and IT has refused to give me admin rights. Will it fix the problem if I were able to do that?

Comment: If you are a university student, is there anything preventing you from just using your own laptop?

Comment: my laptop isnt good enough to run my data files as I work with population data